# org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException exception when trying to execute cmd in Java

Tags: java, cmd, yolo, darknet

This is the error I get.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: -1073741515 (Exit value: -1073741515)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:153)
    at Main.main(Main.java:72)
```

And here's the code:

```
String line = "cmd.exe /C darknet.exe detect cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights -ext_output data/dog.jpg > results.txt";
CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
executor.setWorkingDirectory(new File("F:/yolov3/darknet"));
int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
System.out.println(exitValue);
```

And if I try alternatives of this (ProcessBuilder or Runtime.getRuntime().exec() on String[] of cmds) I get the same bad output (not necessarily the error, but the process exit code).

The command I run from cmd is

```
F:\yolov3\darknet>darknet.exe detect cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights -ext_output data/dog.jpg > results.txt
```

And this gives the correct/expected output.

I've been looking for answers for a couple of hours, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why use cmd.exe? Just start darknet.exe directly.

Comment: That still gives me the same ExitValue code (-1073741515)

Comment: You may need to use absolute paths (e.g. for cfg/yolov3.cfg).

Comment: Could try with something simple like:
String line = "cmd.exe /C hostname > results.txt";

Comment: I have, I also tried with dir. Simple programs work. But running darknet doesn't.

Comment: I guess some env variables are missing, you could try to run set command in cmd.exe and check those... try use execute(cmdLine, mapEnv) method than